# Trying to change margin using javascript and media query

Tags: javascript, html, css

guys here is a simple calendar and i want to change margin-left property usin javascript. I use simple javascript code. here is a whole demo: http://buhehe.de/kalender-2018/

```
<script>
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("calendar");
var newmargin = (x - 222)/2;
var mq = window.matchMedia('@media all and (max-width: 500px)');
if( mq.matches) {
table.style.marginLeft = "newmargin ";
}  
</script>
```

The calendar width is 222px. My goal is to set them in Center in Mobile. So i try tu get first mobile screen width, then i minus 222px and divide it by 2. Which must be a margin-left value.
But it does change nothing

Comment: hello, your calendars are set in `display: inline-block`. Why not adding `text-align: center` to your div `.traki` ?

Comment: By the way, it's probably unrelated, but you have multiple div with the same id `#januar`

Comment: `var table = document.getElementsByClassName("calendar");` gets you a DOM **collection**. You probably mean to use the first element of that collection using `var table = document.getElementsByClassName("calendar")[0];`. Then, go `table.style.marginLeft = newmargin + 'px';`

Comment: Are you attempting to center the `calendar-container` in the window?

Comment: I see you used my solution in your website, but no upvote?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do few changes in your code like

```
table.style.marginLeft = "newmargin";
```

to

```
table.style.marginLeft = newmargin +"px";
```

And

```
window.matchMedia('@media all and (max-width: 500px)')
```

to

```
window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 500px)')
```

> **[Reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)**

```js
var w = window,
  d = document,
  e = d.documentElement,
  g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
  x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
  y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
var table = d.getElementsByClassName("calendar")[0];
var newmargin = (x - 222) / 2;
console.log(newmargin+"px")
var mq = window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 700px)');
if (mq.matches) {
  table.style.marginLeft = newmargin +"px";
}
```

```css
.calendar{width:222px;height:40px;background:red;}
```

```html
<div class="calendar"></div>
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("calendar");
```

gets you a DOM **collection**, not a single DOM element.

You probably mean to use the first element of that collection using

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("calendar")[0];
```

Then, go

```
table.style.marginLeft = newmargin + 'px';
```

Last but not least you need to fix your call to `window.matchMedia()`:

```
window.matchMedia('all and (max-width: 500px)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably setting the `newmargin` as a string and not as the variable value, try this:

```
if( mq.matches) {
   table.style.marginLeft = newmargin + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you do ***not need javascript*** to achieve your goal.  You can simply add ***`text-align: center`*** to the containing class element, ***`.traki`***.

```
.traki {
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you are only looking to center the calendar elements, you can nest the month classes in a wrapper and apply ***`text-align: center`***.

For example

**HTML**

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="Februar">...</div>
        <div class="Maerz">...</div>
        ...
        <div class="Dezember">...</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #wrapper {
        text-align: center;
    }
```